# wp_handle_upload to overwrite existing file with same name?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to force wp_handle_upload to overwrite a file with the same name as the one being uploaded:
this is my current code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
            $uploadedfile = $_FILES['myfile'];
            $new_filename="amine";
            $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
            $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
```

Comment: Looks valid for me. Any errors?

Comment: add `var_dump($movefile)` and show the response.

Comment: yes It is a valid code,but I need to replace the file if an existing one is in the upload folder

Comment: Answer here : [use the unique_filename_callback][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382934/rename-and-overwrite-uploaded-files

Answer (score 3):

i think you can force overwrite the existing file with the same name by adding custom `wp_unique_filename` callback, pass it on `$upload_overrides` args like this

```
...
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false, , 'unique_filename_callback' => 'your_custom_callback' );
...

function your_custom_callback($dir, $name, $ext){
    return $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use unlink($filePath) first to delete the file that is already there and then you can execute the upload.

Comment: I like your approach, but here's the official version -> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_file/

Comment: I recommend this doc as well.